# Login problem

Tags: login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 10.10 login problem..](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32795/ubuntu-10-10-login-problem)

I cannot enter to the normal Login interface.. if I do it will enter into tty1 mode..
I just can enter using recovery mode...
How can I solve this problem???