# Login screen problem, boots into text mode instead of GDM

Tags: gdm, login

I cannot enter to the normal Login interface. If I do it will enter into tty1 mode. I just can enter using recovery mode. How can I solve this problem?

This happened 3 month before and after I just updating the Ubuntu. It was just a normal update.

I'm using Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat 10.10 and I think the problem is related to the plymouth manager.

Comment: We need more information. What Ubuntu version and have you updated something?

Comment: Did you try the recovery mode (usually available from the Grub boot manager menu) and reconfigure your xorg.conf ?

Comment: Try pressing `shift` during boot and get to grub menu. edit it with `e` command and replace `quiet splash` with `text` and press `ctrl+x`. If your system boots you will be prompted for username and password. Then try `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start` and see if you could get into login window or may be `startx` on your tty1 mode may also help.

Comment: maybe: 
sudo service gdm start
sudo service gdm restart

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

First step is to login with a shell and look at /var/log/syslog for errors.

Researching `/etc/init.d/gdm restart` issues might help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Nvidia graphiccard? If so, your xorg.conf could have been messed up somehow. 
A

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

could help.

Comment: i don't have nvidia graphic card..