# lubuntu 16.04 login problems

Tags: lubuntu, login

I have a Notebook with Lubuntu 16.04 running on it.
Today I was trying to install android on an sd card using the OSMC installer. The install program did crash all the time (I've tried 3 times). The only way to close the installer was to log out and back in, which I did. But the 3rd time I tried it, the installer crashed again, and I did log out again planning to look for another solution after I did login again.

But that moment never came. I got stuck on the login screen. Every time I try to login I got thrown back to the login screen. I've tried to use a wrong password on purpose to see if it's me by using the wrong login details, but then I get a warning that I've used the wrong details. So I'm sure I use the right ones.

I've found on [this (closed) thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32795/login-screen-problem-boots-into-text-mode-instead-of-gdm) a way to login the terminal way and to install pastebinit by running `sudo apt-get install pastebinit` This should solve the problem. But when I try that, I get this message: `E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.`

So I went searching online how to clean /var/cache/apt/archives/. I've found in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65549/var-cache-apt-archives-occupying-huge-space) that I should use the `sudo apt-get clean` command and/or `sudo apt-get autoclean` to clean this folder. But this doesn't give me any result.

So I'm still stuck in the login screen. Does anybody know where I should start to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [dillthedog](https://discourse.osmc.tv/users/dillthedog) on the OSMC forums, I got it solved!

Press `CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1` to get the terminal screen

Enter this to see the files in your home folder:

```
cd
du -s *
```

Look for files that are real big (in my case the android installer for my vero2 device) and type

```
rm filename.extension
```

It's done in a blink of an eye, but try to reboot and the problem is solved!